# jQueryMobile + Phonegap + Android: Jumping screen when typing

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

Almost same problem: [Screen Scrolls while typing Using JQTouch in an Android PhoneGap app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069463/screen-scrolls-while-typing-using-jqtouch-in-an-android-phonegap-app)

I still experienced this in my app, whenever the user types in an text input field, the screen jumps.

The only fixed that I include are:

html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

and

Android Manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Anyone know any fix for this jumping screen problem?

Comment: Try this. The highest ranking solution solved my problem!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069463/screen-scrolls-while-typing-using-jqtouch-in-an-android-phonegap-app